# VB DataGridView Not Displaying on Filename.vb[Design]

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

This seems crazy to me but here's what happened,

I had a gridview that was inside a Panel, The Panel was inside of a TabControl. I accidentally selected "remove tab" while the tab control was selected so it deleted all of the contents that were within the control, including my datagridview. I quickly did ctr + z to undo what I had deleted however, only the tab control and Panel reappeared. I can't see the gridview at all and I have tried to use "send to back" and "bring to front" for both the panel and the tab control thinking it was hiding behind it but I still don't see the DatagridView control.

What blows my mind even more is that I tried to just add another DataGridView and rename it to be the same name as the one that disappeared and it tells me "The name DataGridView1 is already in use by another component."

If I go to my Filename.Designer.vb, the old datagridview control is still there.

Why can't I see the control on the screen anymore and why can't I rename a new datagridview to replace my old one??

Comment: if `the old datagridview control is still there` you cant use the same name.  Open the Filename.Designer.vb and set the DGV's location to 0,0, then scroll down and see if it is added to the Controls collection of anything.  Probably not, so at the bottom, add `Me.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView1)`.  save, then re open the form in the designer.  It should show on the form so you can move it to where you want

Comment: I guess you are using visual studio, it's always good to mention which version. Your case seems to be one of these occasional glitches with the visual studio designer. I suggest closing visual studio, open the designer file in another text editor, make sure the grid is there (or remove it if you want to replace it) then re-open the project and **build** before you ask to display the designer view.

Comment: Thank You, Adding the Me.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView1) did the trick. I am not very familiar with WinForms Application development and for the layout I cheat and just drag and drop controls, so i couldn't tell exactly what all needed to be included in the Designer.vb file.